# Selected value based on ID in EntityType

Tags: symfony-3.4, formbuilder

I want the EntityType (DefaulList) to choose the default value based on the ID from the Data entity.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('mpkId', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => MpkList::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'mpk'
            ))
            ->add("time", IntegerType::class)
            ->add("submit", SubmitType::class);
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(["data_class"=>Data::class]);
    }
```

example: Data['mpkId']=1, MpkList['id'=>1,'mpk'=>'description']. Selected field in form 'description'

Comment: If you want to create a choice list based on entity id, so your list will contains only 1 data ? because the id is unique , isn't that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback function . And access to all objects in your MpkList Class.
something like this

```
   ->add('mpkId', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => MpkList::class,
                'choice_label' => function (MpkList $MpkList) {
                    return "id=".$MpkList->getId()."-Description=". $MpkList->getMpkId()->getDescription();

                },
            ))
```

Comment: But not in this case. Option is not selected based on the relation Data ID and MpkList ID. That's what I mean. I'm sorry how wrong I expressed myself